# JUnit test to retrieve all entities fails with actual result '[]'

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, spring-data-jpa, mockito

I am trying to test my method for getting back all entities that exist in my db. I am using JUnit and Mockito. I have no experience with testing so far and this is how far I've got:
This is my method from the agency service to get back all entities, using the findAll() function of JpaRepository:

```
      public List<AgencyDto> getAll() {
        return repo.findAll().stream().map(agency -> mapper.mapToDto(agency)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AgencyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private AgencyRepository agencyRepository;


    @InjectMocks
    private AgencyService agencyService;

    @Test
    void getAgencies() {
      
        List<Agency> existingAgencies = new ArrayList<Agency>();
        Agency agency1 = new Agency();
        Agency agency2 = new Agency();

        existingAgencies.add(agency1);
        existingAgencies.add(agency2);

        when(agencyRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(existingAgencies);

        List<AgencyDto> result = agencyService.getAll();

        assertEquals(existingAgencies, result);
    }
}
```

When running the test, the value for expected seems ok, but the value for actual is an empty array:

```
Expected :[com.project.DTOs.AgencyDto@245a26e1, com.project.DTOs.AgencyDto@4d63b624, com.project.DTOs.AgencyDto@466cf502]
Actual   :[]
```

Is this not the right way to test get() methods? Am I doing something wrong when setting the actual result?

Comment: how did you mock agencyRepository?

Comment: Can you share how `agencyRepository` is mocked, and how (if?) it's then injected to the `agencyService`?

Comment: have you debugged your test?

Comment: yes, it fails on the last line, on the assertEquals(). This is what I'm getting: `at com.project.AgencyServiceTest.get(AgencyServiceTest.java:108)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)`

Comment: have you checked whether repo.findAll() actually returns the result you expect?

Comment: yes, I've tested it in Postman, the method works just fine

Comment: 'existingAgencies' used to mock method call is an empty List, that's the reason you assert fails, you had initialize that but it doesn't have any items

Comment: @Alessia I meant during your test, which is why I asked you if you had debugged

Comment: Yes, I have, and the result of repo.findAll() is ok

Answer (score 2):

if i understand your code coreectly
`agencyRepository.findAll()` return `List<Agency>`
`agencyService.getAll()` return  `List<AgencyDto>`

Issue is here

```
  List<Agency> existingAgencies = new ArrayList<Agency>();
  when(agencyRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(existingAgencies);
```

your mock returns an empty list, you need to add items to list

eg:

```
List<Agency> existingAgencies = new ArrayList<Agency>();
existingAgencies.add(agencyObjectInDB1);
existingAgencies.add(agencyObjectInDB2);
existingAgencies.add(agencyObjectInDB3);
//Mock repo call
when(agencyRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(existingAgencies);  

//I assume Here inside getAll() , agencyRepository.findAll() is invoked
//getAll() converts Agency to AgencyDto
List<AgencyDto> result = agencyService.getAll();

// assert against pre-pepared list 
assertEquals(agencies, result);
```

Comment: Something is still wrong, because now the result is `[null, null, null]`. Maybe it's something wrong with the mapping? Because the method in my service returns an AgencyDto, but the JpaRepository method returns an Agency. I've updated the code

Comment: I've mapped agency1 and agency2 to an Agency, and I've added only them to existingAgencies, but the result is still `[null, null]`

Comment: I miss that point of DTO  still, my answer will be the same , you need to add dummy dto objects into list . I'm not sure what is your Mapper is in the updated code

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: But in this way am I not comparing 2 identical things? And what do you mean by missing to mock `agencyService.getAll()` ? I have mocked the service and calling methods from it works for other tests.

Comment: I misunderstood your test, ignore my comment about `agencyService.getAll()`. so you are having null objects in list , which means `mapper.mapToEntity(agency1)`is returning null. that's what you need to check.check my updated

Comment: I have updated the code. Theresult still returns [null, null]. The only good thing is that the size of result is the same as the size of existingAgencies so maybe I could compare the sizes? This way the test would pass.